# How to add more File names and Header Names in the code

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to fix the issue but its something beyond my knowledge.

I want to extract more columns data by adding `"Header Name"` in the code. But my code works only for single header.

I tried to add an array like this

`Const sHeader As String = Array("Category", "Names")` and so on.

but I get an error.

I want to `Add File Names` to loop through them in the folder and skip rest of the files.

Like this `Const sFileName As String = Array("File1", "File2")` and so on.

**i want to copy and paste each Column through its Header Separat.**

I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

```
Sub ImportColumns()
    
    ' Source
    Const sFilePattern As String = "*.xlsx"
    Const sExceptionsList As String = "Sheet1" ' comma-separated, no spaces
    Const sHeader As String = "Category"
    Const sHeaderRow As Long = 1
    ' Destination
    Const dColumn As String = "A"
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sfd As FileDialog
    Set sfd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    'sfd.InitialFileName = "C:\Test\"
    
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    
    If sfd.Show Then
        sFolderPath = sfd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    Else
        'MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sFilePattern)
    
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "No files found.", vbExclamation
        Beep
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sExceptions() As String: sExceptions = Split(sExceptionsList, ",")
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dColumn).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    ' Loop.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim shrg As Range
    Dim sData() As Variant
    Dim sfCell As Range
    Dim slCell As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    Dim wsCount As Long
    
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFolderPath & sFileName)
        For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
            If IsError(Application.Match(sws.Name, sExceptions, 0)) Then
                Set shrg = sws.Rows(sHeaderRow)
                Set sfCell = shrg.Find(sHeader, shrg.Cells(shrg.Cells.Count), _
                        xlFormulas, xlWhole)
                If Not sfCell Is Nothing Then
                    Set sfCell = sfCell.Offset(1)
                    Set slCell = sfCell _
                        .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sHeaderRow) _
                        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
                    If Not slCell Is Nothing Then
                        srCount = slCell.Row - sHeaderRow
                        Set srg = sfCell.Resize(srCount)
                    End If
                End If
                If srCount > 0 Then
                    If srCount = 1 Then
                        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
                    Else
                        sData = srg.Value
                    End If
                    dfCell.Resize(srCount).Value = sData
                    Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(srCount)
                    wsCount = wsCount + 1
                    srCount = 0
                End If
            End If
        Next sws
        swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop
                
    ' Save the destination workbook.
    'dwb.Save
                
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox wsCount & " '" & sHeader & "' columns copied.", vbInformation
                
End Sub
```

Comment: Think of `Array` in VBA more as a function call than a compiler directive (because it is). Since a `Const` cannot execute a function call and must be a constant, you can't initialize an array that way.

Comment: Then how to initialize the Array if that way its not possible. I would apprecite your help.

Comment: Any help on this @VBasic2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, "Do While" loops are quite slow, I would try to avoid them. Instead, use defined "For" or "For each" loops.

The key is to use Arrays, and in every "For" loop ask for the information stored in these arrays.

Here is an idea (it is not finished) using "For" loops, one inside other one. The first is to Open Files, second to Open Sheets and the third to check the Headers. Please check the variables "arrFiles(X)" und "arrHeaders(Y)"

```
Dim wbkSheet    As Worksheet
Dim Wbk         As Workbook
Dim X           As Double, Y As Double
Dim sHeaderRow  As Byte: sHeaderRow = 1
Dim shRg        As Range, sfCell As Range

'Here we set the values for the Files names and Table Headers names. They'll be Arrays
Dim arrFiles    As Variant: arrFiles = Array("File_1.xlsx", "Files_2.xlsx")
Dim arrHeader   As Variant: arrHeader = Array("Category", "Names")

'Loop to check every file that is in the Array
For X = LBound(arrFiles, 1) To UBound(arrFiles, 1)
  'Loop to open every file of the list
  'Example:
    Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(sFolderPath & arrFiles(X))
  '...
    For Each wbkSheet In Wbk.Worksheets
    'Loop to open every sheet of the opened file.
        For Y = LBound(arrHeader, 1) To UBound(arrHeader, 1)
         'Loop to check every column of the sheet
         'Example:
            Set shRg = wbkSheet.Rows(sHeaderRow)
            Set sfCell = shRg.Find(arrHeader(Y), shRg.Cells(shRg.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
         '...
        Next Y
        
    Next wbkSheet
Next X
```

With this code, you might be able to add as many files and headers you want.

Now, in my opinion the best solution will be to use ADO Excel, it is way faster (it uses SQL queries) and you don't need to open the files. The loops will be much shorter because you just stablish SQL Queries.

Comment: Thank you very much i will surely work on this.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion to initialize your array using a `Const` would be to declare the headers this way:

```
Const ALL_HEADERS As String = "Category,Names"
```

Then later, when you set up your array it will be:

```
Dim sHeader() As String
sHeader = Split(ALL_HEADERS, ",")
```

And your array is set.

Comment: Thank you  i did this and then same logic applied to the columns. IF there are two header needs to be search then there data will pasted into 2 separate columns. But this thing is not working for the columns