# Getting unique values for multiple column separatly

Tags: excel, vba

What is worng with my function its loading the two different column `A` and `B` and pasting the unique values of column `A` into Column `M` and `N`.

I want to repeat this function for the 7 columns.

I would appreciate your help in this regards.

```
Sub GetUniques()

Dim d As Object, c As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long, lr2 As Long, lr3 As Long, lr4 As Long, lr5 As Long, lr6 As Long
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = Range("A2:A" & lr)

lr2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
e = Range("B2:B" & lr2)

For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
  d(c(i, 1)) = 1
Next i

For i = 1 To UBound(e, 1)
  d(e(i, 1)) = 1
Next i

Range("M2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
Range("N2").Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
End Sub
```

Comment: Which version excel do you use. In Excel 365 there is a built in UNIQUE-function

Comment: Yes i am using Excel 365 but [After using this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73025770/how-to-add-more-header-in-the-code-to-extract-the-data) i have to get  unique values for each of column. using VBA

Comment: This may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204826/excel-unique-across-columns

Comment: Hey thank you @urdearboy but its not relatable because i want each column unique values to be pasted in separate column, For Example Column `A,B,C,D,E` unique values will pasted in Column `J,K,L,M,N`

Comment: Could you please clarify: in column J you want unique values of column A, in column K you want unique values of column B etc?

Comment: Yes you are right @Ike

Comment: Create a Column Loop

Comment: Or use `=UNIQUE(A:A)` as Formula in `J2` - it will spill down automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your plan is to have a `lr` variable for each column as well as loops and transpose statements. You can avoid this by nesting your code in a column loop.

The current Column range is hard coded here (`A to E`) but this can be updated to be dynamic as needed. The output is also hard coded to be dropped 9 columns to the right of the input column. This aligns with `A to J`, `B to K`, etc.

---

```
Sub GetUniques()

Dim c As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long, col As Long
Dim d As Object

For col = 1 To 5     'Column A to E

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
        lr = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        c = Range(Cells(2, col), Cells(lr, col))
    
        For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
            d(c(i, 1)) = 1
        Next i
    
        Cells(2, col + 9).Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
    
    Set d = Nothing

Next col


End Sub
```

---

Comment: I actually was looking for this solution instead of repeating Unique function for each column Separalty. Thank you very much.

Comment: @urdearboy: I added the UNIQUE-solution as an alternative solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am adding the `UNIQUE`- solution - for completeness:

You can either use a manual formula in `J2`: `=UNIQUE(A:E,TRUE)` - the second parameter tells `UNIQUE` to put out unique values *per column* --> it will spill from `J` to `N`.

You can use this formula in a VBA-routine as well:

```vb
Public Sub writeUniqueValues(rgSource As Range, rgTargetTopLeftCell As Range)

With rgTargetTopLeftCell
    .Formula2 = "=UNIQUE(" & rgSource.Address & ",TRUE)"
    With .SpillingToRange
       .Value = .Value 'this will replace the formula by values
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

You can then use this sub like this:

```vb
Public Sub test_writeUniqueValues()

With ActiveSheet 'be careful: you should always use explicit referencing
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    writeUniqueValues .Range("A2:E" & lr), .Range("J2")
End With

End Sub
```

It would be interesting to compare performance of both solutions (using the formula vs. using a dictionary) ...

Comment: Thank you very much indeed its a good appraoch.